# CQL query to return a boolean column based on a condition

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is it possible to retrieve a true/false answer from a CQL query that checks a condition -- for example, if a collection has a specific value?

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Id text PRIMARY KEY, Roles set<text>)

INSERT INTO Test(Id, Roles)
    VALUES ('123', {'Driver', 'Pilot', 'Janitor'})
```

I would like to get a true or false value depending on whether or not the set associated with `Id='123'` contains a specific value. Here is an imaginary syntax for what I'd like to get; it does not work:

```
SELECT
    Roles CONTAINS 'Pilot' // <<== Not a valid syntax; this does not work
FROM Test
WHERE Id = '123'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ok, here's what I came up with in the airport, quick...*

Unfortunately, Cassandra CQL doesn't have a lot of the things that folks have grown accustomed to in SQL.  For the problem of querying by `id` and `roles CONTAINS 'Pilot'`, I came up with a similar solution.

```
CREATE TABLE roles (Id text, Roles set<text>);
CREATE INDEX on roles(roles);
```

Although, I used a secondary index to permit filtering on the `roles` collection.

The boolean is a little trickier.  I created a user defined function (setting `user_defined_functions_enabled: true` in my cassandra.yaml).

Then the UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION textToBoolean (input TEXT)
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE java AS 'if (!input.equals("True")) { return false; }
                  return Boolean.valueOf(input);';
```

And then this works:

```
SELECT texttoboolean('True') AS success FROM roles WHERE id='123' AND roles CONTAINS 'Pilot';

 success
---------
    True

(1 rows)
```

All the UDF really does is let you return a boolean True if you really need to.  So it returns true if it works, but returns nothing if it doesn't.  Your solution of returning the `COUNT` might work better depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to obtain a 1 or 0 result using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Test
WHERE Id = '123' AND Roles CONTAINS 'Pilot'
ALLOW FILTERING
```

You need `ALLOW FILTERING` to suppress a performance warning.